# Error creating new Topology

Tags: web8, topology-manager

could anyone helps me to create a New Topology?

[image]

I don't know what is wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message states rather explicitly: your Topology Type defines two environment purposes: "Staging" and "Live".

If you want to create a Topology of that Type, you will have to provide exactly two CD Environment IDs: one for a CD Environment with purpose "Staging" and one with purpose "Live".

You only provided one CD Environment ID (with purpose "Staging") and hence your Topology doesn't meet the constraints of the Topology Type.